# joomla get input setting the date format in calendar tag

Tags: date, joomla, calendar, formatting, components

I have a calendar input box in my joomla component.  The XML for the calendar element is:

```
        <field name="dob" type="calendar"

        label="COM_OPTICAL_DATABASE_FORM_LBL_PATIENTDETAIL_DOB"
        description="COM_OPTICAL_DATABASE_FORM_DESC_PATIENTDETAIL_DOB" 
        format="%d-%m-%Y"    


        filter="raw" />
```

Which has the right date format.  However the input box in the form shows up as

Y-m-d

I want to reformat it to the correct date

I found this which puts in the current date:

```
                <div class="tablecol1 zebra1">
                     <?php echo $this->form->getLabel('dob'); ?>:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="tablecol2 ">
                    <?php echo $this->form->getInput('dob', '', date('d-m-Y')); ?>
```

but I want it to put in the date I retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a work around since no one seems to have the answer.  I think Joomla either doesn't allow this or there is some way of doing it buried somewhere in the documentation.  Anyway for anyone else struggling to make this work:

```
 <?php
 $birthDate1 = $this->form->getValue('dob');
 $birthDateHolder = explode("-", $birthDate1);
 $changed = $birthDateHolder[2]."-".$birthDateHolder[1]."-".$birthDateHolder[0];
 echo $this->form->getInput('dob', '', $changed); 
 ?>
```

I've tested this and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php 
   echo $this->form->getInput('dob', '', JFactory::getDate('dob')->format('d-m-Y')); 
?>
```

OR:

```
<?php 
   echo $this->form->getInput(JFactory::getDate('dob')->format('d-m-Y'), ''); 
?>
```

Please note I haven't tested it so let me know if it works

Comment: This throws a 500 error DateTime::__construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse time string